# MySQL: difference between CR_CONN_HOST_ERROR and CR_SERVER_GONE_ERROR

Tags: mysql

What is the difference between CR_CONN_HOST_ERROR (2003) and CR_SERVER_GONE_ERROR (2006) error codes?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-client.html First google result for either code.

Comment: I can google. But for me difference between 'can't connect' and 'server gone away' is unclear. What does it mean -- 'gone away' -- in terms of sockets?

Comment: Was connected but isn't connected any more?